# Dissolve column based on attribute in another column

Tags: arcmap, polygon, vector, tools, dissolve

I have 3 columns within a polygon layer I'm working with.

Column 1 = Landowner, 3 different values
Column 2 = Parcel, N different values
Column 3 = Management type, 5 different values

I would like to dissolve column 3 based on unique values in column 2, and again within column 1.

Example
C1 = A, B, C
C2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
C3 = Z, Y, X

A     1     Z
A     1     Z
A     1     Y
A     2     X
A     2     Z
A     2     Z
B     1     Z
B     1     Y

Results
A     1     Z
A     1     Y
A     2     X
A     2     Z
B     1     Z
B     1     Y

Is there a tool in any version of ArcMap that I can set this up in or will I have to create something within the model builder or python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dissolve command (found in the toolbox).
Dissolve on C1, C2 and C3. decide if you want to save any statics and what type.
Then decide how you want the geometry to be handled.
Probably uncheck the multipart.

[image]

if it works from there you can easily create a modelbuilder for it.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed this.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap you could make a new field and then calculate it to

`[Field1] + " " + [Field2] + " " + [Field3]`

Then dissolve on the new field.

If one of the fields is numeric, convert it to a string

`str([Field1])`