# Grouping vector file column attributes under another column's attribute as a hierarchy group

Tags: attribute-table

I would like to output attributes in a vector file I have for Land use. There are three categories that are in hierarchical order. The columns represented in the attributes table are:

PRIMARY_20 > SECONDARY_ > TERTIARY_2

I would like to display the TERTIARY_2 column attributes but group them under their PRIMARY_20 category so it looks like this:

PRIMARY_20 (no symbology, just group heading)

[image](grouped below PRIMARY_20) TERTIARY_2 (with symbology displayed in the map layers panel and in the map legend (layout))

I have tried the method outlined here (I added the SECONDARY column just as a test): [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34428/dissolve-column-based-on-attribute-in-another-column[![enter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34428/dissolve-column-based-on-attribute-in-another-column%5B!%5Benter) image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFNNR.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFNNR.png)

and my own method trying to concatenate (see figure attached). [image]

I can get the column attributes to join but cannot space them ( I have tried ' ' between concatenate) and tried to insert a new line before TERTIARY_2 (using '\n' function) to no avail. [image]

I have attached figures to try and explain visually.